# SQL datetime to string format

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, datetime, insert

I have some code which declares an object variable, and this variable is assigned a value from an existing database field.

```
Dim datestart As Object
datestart = dbToDate(dr("DateStart"))
```

The variable is then passed through  a function which checks whether or not it is null, and then converts it into datetime data type.

```
     Public Shared Function dbToDate(o As Object) As DateTime

    If o Is DBNull.Value Then
        Return Nothing

    Else
        Return Convert.ToDateTime(o)

    End If
End Function
```

The last thing I need to do with it is convert it into a date formatted string, DD/MM/YYYY, so that I can insert it into a new database.

The function that I have so far is

```
Public Shared Function sqlDate(dt As DateTime) As String

    Return "'" & Format(dt, "yyyyMMdd") & "'"

End Function
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error message

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Check the values in your table for the DateStart column. One or more rows contain values which are out of range specified for c# DateTime type.

Comment: @TheShooter This is vb.net, not c#

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to note the language but language is irrelevant. Underlying data type of all .net languages are same. Put a breakpoint on datestart = dbToDate(dr("DateStart")) statement, check value of dr("DateStart") and see if it lies between DateTime.Mix and DateTime.Max. Alternatively note down the value of DateTime.Min and DateTime.Max and in the sql table find rows that have value out of this range.

Comment: @TheShooter the value is 3/1/2014

Comment: It's a normal value. You would need to check all the values in the table. Some value in the table is out of the range. Run a SELECT query on the table and check each row.

Comment: @TheShooter The answer below fixed my problem, I was just using the wrong syntax

Comment: Ypu probably don't need to convert the `DateTime` to a string, instead look at parametrising your queries.

Comment: DateTime variables do not have a format.  Your NET db providers are perfectly capable of passing DataTime variables and storing them.  Formats are just for how computers and apps show dates to people.  Your database should be storing dates as dates not varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can use `toString` function. Also check your timezone. The problem might be in the time zone setting.

Hope you are passing date as string to database, Try to pass date as Datetime variable rather than string

```
Public Shared Function sqlDate(dt As DateTime) As String

    Return dt.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")

End Function
```

For your Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry Sankar, my mistake, it's because I'd added hhmmss tt at the end of the string. However, one of my dates is null, and in the function called dbToDate (see question), instead of returning 'Nothing' it returns 12:00:00AM, so this function won't work to insert it into the database. How do I get this to work with these?

Comment: @joe 
 So you are concatenating time with date. right?

Comment: I want the value to just be a date. In the database, there are 4 datetimes. 3 representing dates without times, the 4th representing a time without a date. 1 date and the time field allow nulls. With the time field, this works fine as it is converted to Nothing. However, the null date is converted to a time, which is causing the issue